# How to send user input in the javaScriptExecutor in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to send user input using scanner class in a text box using javaScriptExecutor but not getting the value which is captured taken by the scanner class.

```
    Scanner first_captcha = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the captcha");
            int Captcha = first_captcha.nextInt();

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            WebElement captcha = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("captcha")));
            JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('captcha').value = Captcha");


   /* Value is going to the textbox is "Captcha" but I just wanted to send the value which user provided in the scanner class. */
```

Comment: Any reason to use `JavascriptExecutor`? Any issue with `sendKeys()`?

Comment: The field in which I'm trying to send value is not working using sendkeys() because that field is not getting detected using driver.findElement(). Hence I'm trying to use javaScriptExecutor. Please let me know if any further details required. @DebanjanB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('captcha').value = Captcha");
```

Here `Captcha` is hard coded string which you have set. you have to pass `Captch` as variable which you are getting using Scanner class.

Use below code :

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('captcha').value = "+Captcha+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
jse.executeScript(String.format("document.getElementById('captcha').value = %d", Captcha));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your execution string has no place holder for integer value. So you need to refactor the jse.executeScript call according to this syntax.

```
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('captcha').value = "+Captcha+";");
```